# Can't render different meshes with different VAO on OpenGL

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, opengl-3

For some weird reason I can't seem to render different generated meshes. I have a class which generates the appropriate buffers and vaos for each instance. The idea of the class is for me to generate primitives. I add a member of this class to BoxGeometry and SphereGeometry each. If I render only 1 type there's no problem but if I render two different types it renders only 1 type of primitive and incorrectly.

Here's the base geometry generator:

```
#pragma once

// GLAD
#include <vector>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

class GeometryGenerator {

public:
    GeometryGenerator() : buffer(64), ibuffer(192) {
        buffer.clear();
        ibuffer.clear();
        generated = false;
    }

    void emitVertex() {
        buffer.push_back(currentVertex);
    }

    void emitTriangle() {
        ibuffer.push_back(currentTriangle[0]);
        ibuffer.push_back(currentTriangle[1]);
        ibuffer.push_back(currentTriangle[2]);
    }

    void declareVertexPosition(float x, float y, float z) {
        currentVertex.position[0] = x;
        currentVertex.position[1] = y;
        currentVertex.position[2] = z;
    }

    void declareVertexNormal(float x, float y, float z) {
        currentVertex.normal[0] = x;
        currentVertex.normal[1] = y;
        currentVertex.normal[2] = z;
    }

    void declareTriangle(std::uint32_t x, std::uint32_t y, std::uint32_t z) {
        currentTriangle[0] = x;
        currentTriangle[1] = y;
        currentTriangle[2] = z;
        emitTriangle();
    }

    void generate() {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertex) * buffer.size(), buffer.data(),
                     GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(std::uint32_t) * ibuffer.size(), ibuffer.data(),
                     GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // position attribute
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex),
                              (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));

        glBindVertexArray(0);
        generated = true;
    }

    void draw() {
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ibuffer.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

private:
    struct alignas(1) Vertex {
        float position[3];
        float normal[3];
    };

    Vertex currentVertex;
    std::uint32_t currentTriangle[3];
    std::vector<struct Vertex> buffer;
    std::vector<std::uint32_t> ibuffer;
    bool generated;
    unsigned int VAO, VBO, EBO;
};
```

Here's my BoxClass:
    #pragma once

```
#include <memory>
#include "GeometryGenerator.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>
#include "Light.h"

class BoxGeometry {
public:
    static BoxGeometry& getInstance() {
        static BoxGeometry instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void render(const glm::mat4& projection, const glm::mat4& view, const Light& light,
                const Kepler3D::Matrix44& modelMatrix, const Kepler3D::Matrix44& shapeMatrix,
                float length, float width, float height, const glm::vec4& baseColor) {
        glm::mat4 mv;
        std::memcpy(glm::value_ptr(mv), &modelMatrix, sizeof(float)*4*4);
        glm::mat4 sv;
        std::memcpy(glm::value_ptr(sv), &shapeMatrix, sizeof(float)*4*4);
        mainShader->setFloat("boxLength", length);
        mainShader->setFloat("boxWidth", width);
        mainShader->setFloat("boxHeight", height);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.direction", light.direction);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.ambient", light.ambient);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.diffuse", light.diffuse);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.specular", light.specular);
        mainShader->setMat4("ProjectionMatrix", projection);
        mainShader->setMat4("ViewMatrix", view);
        mainShader->setMat4("ModelMatrix", glm::transpose(mv));
        mainShader->setMat4("ShapeMatrix", glm::transpose(sv));
        mainShader->setVec4("baseColor", baseColor);
        mainShader->use();
        geometry.draw();
    }

    BoxGeometry(BoxGeometry const&) = delete;
    void operator=(BoxGeometry const&) = delete;

private:
    void generateGeometry() {
        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(0, 1, 2);
        geometry.declareTriangle(2, 3, 0);

        // bottom

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(4, 5, 6);
        geometry.declareTriangle(6, 7, 4);

        //left

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(8, 9, 10);
        geometry.declareTriangle(10, 11, 8);

        //Right

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(12, 13, 14);
        geometry.declareTriangle(14, 15, 12);

        //Front

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(16, 17, 18);
        geometry.declareTriangle(18, 19, 16);

        //Back

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(-0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareVertexPosition(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f);
        geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        geometry.emitVertex();

        geometry.declareTriangle(20, 21, 22);
        geometry.declareTriangle(22, 23, 20);

        geometry.generate();
    }
    void initShader() {
        mainShader = std::make_unique<Shader>("shaders/VSBox.glsl", "shaders/PSPhong.glsl");
    }
    BoxGeometry() : geometry() {
        generateGeometry();
        initShader();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Shader> mainShader;
    GeometryGenerator geometry;
};
```

and the sphere class:
    #pragma once

```
#include <memory>
#include "GeometryGenerator.h"
#include "shader.h"
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>
#include "Light.h"
#include <math.h>

class SphereGeometry {
public:
    static SphereGeometry& getInstance() {
        static SphereGeometry instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void render(const glm::mat4& projection, const glm::mat4& view, const Light& light,
                const Kepler3D::Matrix44& modelMatrix, const Kepler3D::Matrix44& shapeMatrix,
                float radius, const glm::vec4& baseColor) {
        glm::mat4 mv;
        std::memcpy(glm::value_ptr(mv), &modelMatrix, sizeof(float)*4*4);
        glm::mat4 sv;
        std::memcpy(glm::value_ptr(sv), &shapeMatrix, sizeof(float)*4*4);
        mainShader->setFloat("radius", radius);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.direction", light.direction);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.ambient", light.ambient);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.diffuse", light.diffuse);
        mainShader->setVec3("light.specular", light.specular);
        mainShader->setMat4("ProjectionMatrix", projection);
        mainShader->setMat4("ViewMatrix", view);
        mainShader->setMat4("ModelMatrix", glm::transpose(mv));
        mainShader->setMat4("ShapeMatrix", glm::transpose(sv));
        mainShader->setVec4("baseColor", baseColor);
        mainShader->use();
        geometry.draw();
    }

    SphereGeometry(SphereGeometry const&) = delete;
    void operator=(SphereGeometry const&) = delete;

private:
    void generateGeometry() {
        glm::vec3 top(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        glm::vec3 bottom(0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
        float radius = 0.5f;
        float angleA = 0.f;
        const float pi = 3.14159265f;
        float angleB = pi * 0.5f;
        unsigned int sides = 16;
        unsigned int laterals = 16;
        float advanceX = 2.f*pi / sides;
        float advanceY = pi / laterals;

        unsigned int faceIndex = 0;

        angleB -= advanceY;
        laterals--;
        // Top
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
            geometry.declareVertexPosition(top.x, top.y, top.z);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            geometry.emitVertex();

            geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
            geometry.emitVertex();

            angleA += advanceX;

            geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
            geometry.emitVertex();

            geometry.declareTriangle(faceIndex, faceIndex+1, faceIndex+2);
            faceIndex += 3;
        }

        for(; laterals > 1; laterals--) {
            float cachedB = angleB;
            angleB -= advanceY;
            angleA = 0.f;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {

                geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(cachedB)*radius, sin(cachedB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(cachedB)*radius);
                geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(cachedB), sin(cachedB), sin(angleA)*cos(cachedB));
                geometry.emitVertex();

                geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
                geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
                geometry.emitVertex();

                angleA += advanceX;

                geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(cachedB)*radius, sin(cachedB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(cachedB)*radius);
                geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(cachedB), sin(cachedB), sin(angleA)*cos(cachedB));
                geometry.emitVertex();

                geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
                geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
                geometry.emitVertex();

                geometry.declareTriangle(faceIndex, faceIndex+1, faceIndex+2);
                geometry.declareTriangle(faceIndex+1, faceIndex+3, faceIndex+2);
                faceIndex += 4;
            }
        }

        angleA = 0.f;
        // Bottom
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {

            geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
            geometry.emitVertex();

            angleA += advanceX;

            geometry.declareVertexPosition(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius, sin(angleB)*radius, sin(angleA)*cos(angleB)*radius);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(cos(angleA)*cos(angleB), sin(angleB), sin(angleA)*cos(angleB));
            geometry.emitVertex();

            geometry.declareVertexPosition(bottom.x, bottom.y, bottom.z);
            geometry.declareVertexNormal(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            geometry.emitVertex();

            geometry.declareTriangle(faceIndex, faceIndex+2, faceIndex+1);
            faceIndex += 3;
        }

        geometry.generate();
    }
    void initShader() {
        mainShader = std::make_unique<Shader>("shaders/VSSphere.glsl", "shaders/PSPhong.glsl");
    }
    SphereGeometry() : geometry() {
        generateGeometry();
        initShader();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Shader> mainShader;
    GeometryGenerator geometry;
};
```

Now I'm not sure if i forgot setting something correctly but in theory I should be able to render instances of each primitive without any trouble but there seems to be a problem with the VAO. I'm using OpenGL 3.3, glfw, glm and a physics engine i created which I'm trying to test. I'm a bit surprised as I'm not an amateur in ogl but I wrote this code out of nothing so I'm not sure what I forgot.

EDIT:
Images:
[Album of images showing different instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHZ7w.jpg)

I checked and there's no memory corruption problem, it seems to point to a problem with ogl.

Comment: Do you have screenshots? What is the behavior of your program, and how does it differ from what you expect/desire?

Comment: Edited and added an album of images showing the problem.

Comment: Are all of the objects using the same shader? But the major problem is, that there is too much code hidden behind functions. For example, which of the shader methods results in a call to `glUseProgram`? I'd suspect `use` which means that the shader gets bound **after** setting the unforms. Since uniform settings always works on the current shader, you are probably setting the uniforms in the wrong shader.

Comment: What is your hardware platform ? Intel ? Nvidia ? AMD ?

Comment: NVIDIA, it was after all uniforms getting corrupted as others mentioned, not really driver problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see all of the code, but this looks suspicious to me:

```
mainShader->setFloat("boxLength", length);
mainShader->...;
mainShader->use();
```

Uniform locations are not unique across different shader programs. If `setFloat` is just a wrapper for [`glUniform1f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUniform.xhtml) or similar, and `use` is `glUseProgram`, this means that the code is setting uniforms on the wrong program!

> glUniform — Specify the value of a uniform variable for the current program object

This is yet another one of those cases where OpenGL's stateful API is biting you, the kind of problem solved with direct state access, other various bindless functions, and newer APIs like Vulkan.

### Easy Solution

Simply put the `use` at the top:

```
mainShader->use();
mainShader->setFloat("boxLength", length);
mainShader->...;
```

### Alternative Solution

If OpenGL 4.1 is an option, you have the [`glProgramUniform`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/) operations which are not affected by the currently bound program. This comes from the `GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects` extension.

### Debugging and Detecting the Problem

It's possible that you may not be using `KHR_debug` or calling `glGetError`. Incorrect uniform access *should* generate an `INVALID_OPERATION` error. The best way to see these errors is by creating a debug context and enabling the `KHR_debug` extension. This requires some work to implement, and it doesn't work everywhere (well, it doesn't work on macOS, no prizes for anyone who guessed correctly), but it does save you a lot of time debugging things.